# How to get public key sha 256 hash from x509 with python

Tags: python, openssl, x509, sha256, public-key

I want to calculate sha256 hash of my x509 RootCA cert's public key However my result does not match standarts.(RFC)

```
str(hashlib.sha256(str(crypto.dump_publickey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,x509_cert.get_pubkey())).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Once you extract the base64 of your public key, this is the way to calculate its digest with python:

```
import base64
import hashlib    
b64pubkey="MIIBojANBgkqhkiG9w0................."
print(hashlib.sha256(base64.b64decode(b64pubkey)).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 0):

Full example using cryptography:

```
from hashlib import sha256
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate

with open(Path(BASE_PATH, cert_filepath), "rb") as cert_file:
    CERT_DATA = cert_file.read()
CERT = load_pem_x509_certificate(CERT_DATA, default_backend())
CRT_DIGEST = sha256(CERT.public_key().public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)).hexdigest()
```